# How to select same name radio button group?

Tags: codeigniter, radio-button

I have two group of radio button with same name. I want select value from both.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="yes_no">
<div>
<input id="5"  class="radio1" type="radio"  name="CorrectAnswer[]"   value="1" autocomplete="off">
<label><span>Yes</span> </label>  
<input id="6"  class="radio1" type="radio"  name="CorrectAnswer[]"  value="0" autocomplete="off">
<label><span>No </span></label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="yes_no">
<div>
<input id="3" class="radio" type="radio"  name="CorrectAnswer[]"   value="1"  autocomplete="off" >
<label><span>Yes</span> </label>
<input id="4" class="radio" type="radio" name="CorrectAnswer[]"  value="0" autocomplete="off" >
<label><span>No </span></label>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I choose from both. If it is not working then how can I add ans from both into one filed of database into code igniter with two different row?

Comment: Add some more tags please. Like what language you are using?

Comment: Just to get more understanding, why do you need those radio button groups to have same name?

Comment: I want to add this two answer into one filed of database with two row

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding you, the `<div>` with input id=5, 6 are one field, have one selection, input id=3, 4 are also?  if so, you can set them as two field with different name. That probably what you want.

Comment: Okay I got solution..Thank you all